# Using Magento's ORM to Insert a Specific ID Field

Tags: model

Is there a way to use Magento's simple ORM (`Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` and `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract`) to insert model rows with a specific primary key?

For example, if I ran the following against an empty Magento system

```
Mage::getModel('core/website')->setData(array (
    'website_id' => 2,
    'code' => 'foo',
    'name' => 'Main Website',
    'sort_order' => 0,
    'default_group_id' => 1,
    'is_default' => 1,
));
```

I'd expect a new entry in the `core_website` table.  However, Magento silently does nothing here.

Digging into the resource, it looks like I'm falling afoul of this in the database resource class

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php
if (!is_null($object->getId()) && (!$this->_useIsObjectNew || !$object->isObjectNew())) {
    //update stuff here
}
else
{
    //insert stuff here
}
```

Because the model has an id (i.e. I'm inserting a specific ID), and because `_useIsObjectNew` is hard coded to false, my save request is always routed to the `insert` path.

Is there a way to force an insert with the default Magento models? (without a rewrite/class-replacement).

Yes, raw SQL is an option, but then event functionality gets lost.

Comment: Why are you trying to assign an ID to an autoincrement field?  If this is a downstream dependency shouldn't you just create the record and then retrieve the autogenerated PK?

Comment: @RalphTice Yes, that would probably be the right thing to do for day to day use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, yeah. (*edit:*) The trick is to use a `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` subclass which does not have the id field that the resource model expects:

```
$evil = Mage::getModel('core/store'); // that's a store object, baby!
$evil->setData(
    array (
        'website_id' => 99,
        'code' => 'foo',
        'name' => 'Main Website9',
        'sort_order' => 0,
        'default_group_id' => 1,
        'is_default' => 1,
    )
);

Mage::getResourceModel('core/website')->forsedSave($evil);
```

`Mage::dispatchEvent('website_save_commit_after', [...])` is only event I see being consumed in core. It could be as simple as following with

```
Mage::getModel('core/website')->setData($evil->getData())->afterCommitCallback();
```

In any event, I need a shower.

Comment: Once you're clean — I'm not sure I follow that — there's a similar id check in `forsedSave` https://gist.github.com/astorm/5219357.  Did this work for you, or was it just a theory?

Comment: Edited my answer to make it more obvious.

Comment: ...and it did work for me.

Comment: Ah ha, that's what I get for typing my own code instead of copying and pasting.  Using this as a starting point, can you see any reason not to use a  `Varien_Object` instead of the different model class, and then calling the resource's non depreciated `save` method?

Comment: And answering my own question above, it's because the generic resource's save method has `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` type hinting for the data array.

Comment: Using V_O was my first instinct too, as it would be more proper. But... alas. This seems to be very much by design based on the explicit `unset()` call in `forsedSave()` :-/

Comment: Last word on this before the SE chat police come in — the really weird part is it **seems** like V_O is working for some resources ... which makes no sense, which means I'm stopping this already bad idea.